# Форма Django или сам шаблон не сохраняет картинку профиля

Tags: html, django, django-model

Пытаюсь поменять картинку, но текст сохраняется(first_name, last_name), а картинка нет.
Еще к слову вот как находится путь к аватаркам профиля:
project/media/avatars/и айди профиля
Вот мой код:
models.py:

```
def user_image_dir(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('avatars', f'{instance.user.id}', filename)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_image_dir, blank=True, default='avatars/default.webp')
```

views.py:

```
def profile_edit_page(request):
    form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('todo_list')
            
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'account/profile_edit.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photo = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'custom-file-input', 'type':'file', 'id':'customFile'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

мой шаблон:

```
                <form action="{% url 'profile_edit' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <h6 class="mb-0">Имя</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                                    {% render_field form.first_name class="form-control" %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <h6 class="mb-0">Фамилия</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                                    {% render_field form.last_name class="form-control" %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <h6 class="mb-0">Почта</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                                    {% render_field form.email class="form-control" %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                {{form.photo}}
                                <!-- <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Выберите файл</label> -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4" value="Сохранить изменения">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Дописать `'photo'` в список `fields` в форме, возможно?

Comment: Возможно, но я же сделал виджет, разве нужно его туда вписывать?

Comment: Щас попробую, спасибо

Comment: Круто, работает))