# Данные из формы choices не сохраняеются из фронтэнда, но сохраняются из админки

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, form

Из admin при изменении записи все поля и все выпадающие списки `choices` корректно сохраняются и отображаются на странице, но когда я пытаюсь обновить запись из фронтэнда, то сохраняются только текстовые поля, а выпадающие списки `choices` нет. В чём проблема?

views.py

```py
def create(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewAnzeigenForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            error = 'Ooopps.. Fehler...'

    form = NewAnzeigenForm()
    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }
    return render(request, 'main/create.html', data)
```

models.py

```py
class NewAnzeigen(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)
    preis = models.CharField('Preis', max_length=255)
    telefon = models.CharField('Telefon', max_length=255)
    beschreibung = models.TextField('Beschreibung')
    anzeigenummer = models.CharField('Anzeigenummer', max_length=255)
    standort = models.CharField('Standort', max_length=500)
    online = models.CharField('Online seit', max_length=255)
    url = models.CharField('URL', max_length=1000)
    bild = models.CharField('Bild', max_length=1000)
    rasse = models.CharField('Rasse', max_length=255, choices=RASSEN, default='')
    alter = models.CharField('Alter', max_length=255, default=1)
    grosse = models.CharField('Grosse', max_length=255, default=100)
    geschlecht = models.CharField('Geschlecht', max_length=255, default='')
    art = models.CharField('Art', max_length=255, choices=ART, default='')
    ausbildung = models.CharField('Ausbildung', max_length=255, choices=AUSBILDUNG, default='')
    abstammung = models.CharField('Abstammung', max_length=255, choices=ABSTAMMUNG, default='')
    farbe = models.CharField('Farbe', max_length=255, choices=FARBE, default='')
```

forms.py

```py
from .models import NewAnzeigen
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Textarea
from django import forms


RASSEN = (
    ('araber', 'Araber'),
    ('ha', 'Hispano-Araber'),
    ('cruzado', 'Cruzado'),
    ('lustiano', 'Lustiano'),
    ('pre', 'PRE'),
    ('muli', 'Muli'),
    ('esel', 'Esel'),
)

ART = (
    ('fohlen', 'Fohlen'),
    ('stute', 'Stute'),
    ('hengst', 'Hengst'),
    ('wallach', 'Wallach'),
)

AUSBILDUNG = (
    ('ungeritten', 'Ungeritten'),
    ('geritten', 'Geritten'),
    ('hs', 'Hohe Schule'),
    ('zucht', 'Zucht'),
)

ABSTAMMUNG = (
    ('ja', 'Ja'),
    ('nein', 'Nein'),
)

FARBE = (
            ('falbe', 'Falbe'),
            ('bucksin', 'Bucksin'),
            ('schimmel', 'Schimmel'),
            ('rappe', 'Rappe'),
            ('schecke', 'Schecke'),
            ('ps', 'Porzellanschecke'),
            ('fuchs', 'Fuchs'),
            ('brauner', 'Brauner'),
            ('champagne', 'Champangne'),
            ('cremello', 'Cremello'),
            ('palomino', 'Palomino'),
            ('tg', 'Tigerschecke'),
)

class NewAnzeigenForm(ModelForm):
    rasse = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RASSEN)
    farbe = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FARBE)
    abstammung = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ABSTAMMUNG)
    art = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ART)
    ausbildung = forms.ChoiceField(choices=AUSBILDUNG)
    class Meta:
        model = NewAnzeigen
        fields = ['name', 'beschreibung', 'preis', 'standort', 'telefon', 'alter', 'geschlecht', 'grosse']
        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Name eingeben'
            }),
            'beschreibung': Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Beschreibung eingeben'
            }),
            'preis': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Preis eingeben'
            }),
            'standort': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Ort / Land eingeben'
            }),
            'telefon': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Telefonnummer eingeben'
            }),
            'alter': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Alter eingeben'
            }),
            'grosse': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Größe in cm. eingeben'
            }),
            'geschlecht': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Geschlecht eingeben'
            }),
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class Meta:
        model = NewAnzeigen
        fields = ['name', 'beschreibung', 'preis', 'standort', 'telefon', 'alter', 'geschlecht', 'grosse']
```

Скорее всего не сохраняются потому что не указали поля в `fields`.

Добавьте остальные поля в `Meta.fields` и попробуйте. Должно заработать

Похожая проблема была [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1309089/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-django-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F)